# Function on a measure space such that $f^2 \in L^1(X,\mathbb{A},\mu)$ but $f\notin L^2(X,\mathbb{A},\mu)?$

Tags: measure-theory

Is there an example of a function on a measure space such that $f^2 \in L^1(X,\mathbb{A},\mu)$ but $f\notin L^2(X,\mathbb{A},\mu)?$

I have been trying to think of one but nothing comes to my head... any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is $L^2(X,\mathbb{A},\mu)0?$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy typo sorry

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy could you elaborate this to an answer? I will then accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a non-measurabe set $E$ and let $f=1$ on $E$, $-1$ on $E^{c}$ (on a finite measure space). Since $f^{2}\equiv 1$ we see that $f^{2} \in L^{1}$. Since $f$ is not measurable it follows that $f \notin L^{2}$.